# How to compare time in mysql query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script in php.

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$endTime=$_GET['endTime'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT candidateId from Attendence where candidateId=? and startTime>cast(? as time)");    //This is the problem line
    $stmt->bind_param("ds", $id,$endTime);

 //executing the query 
 $stmt->execute();


 //binding results to the query 
 $stmt->bind_result($var);

 $response = array(); 
 $response['success']=false;

 //traversing through all the result
 if($stmt->fetch())
 {

 $response['success']=true;
 $response['cand']=$var;
 }


 //displaying the result in json format 
 echo json_encode($response);
```

This works fine when I enter this in url bar:

```
http://arnabbanerjee.dx.am/checkAttendenceValidity.php?id=12100116050&endTime='14:30:00'
```

But when I change line 3 as

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT candidateId from Attendence where candidateId=? and startTime<cast(? as time)");
```

and enter this url:

```
http://arnabbanerjee.dx.am/checkAttendenceValidity.php?id=12100116050&endTime='18:30:00'
```

It is showing {"success":false}

This is the entry in the attendence table.

```
12100116050(candidateId)  15:30:00(startTime)  2019-02-05   OS   present   17:30:00(endTime)
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get this problem fixed?

Comment: Why are you quoting your time values in your url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around `endTime`

```
http://arnabbanerjee.dx.am/checkAttendenceValidity.php?id=12100116050&endTime=18:30:00
```

Otherwise the query string will be expanded as:

```
startTime<cast("'18:30:00'" as time)
```

The cast result is NULL.